# Swift:The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to run some audio but I keep getting this error. The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

```swift
func fu(){
        let randomCode = Int.random(in: 0...5000)
        let randomString = randomCode.description
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/\(randomString)")!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            // Check the response
                    print(error)
                    print(response)
            })
            task.resume()
        let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) {
            urlOrNil, responseOrNil, errorOrNil in
            // check for and handle errors:
            // * errorOrNil should be nil
            // * responseOrNil should be an HTTPURLResponse with statusCode in 200..<299
            
            guard let fileURL = urlOrNil else { return }
            do {
                let documentsURL = try
                    FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                            in: .userDomainMask,
                                            appropriateFor: nil,
                                            create: false)
                let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileURL.lastPathComponent)
                print(savedURL)
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL, to: savedURL)
            } catch {
                print ("file error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
        print("cool")
        play(url:url)
        }
    func play(url:URL) {
        print("playing \(url)")
        
        do {
            var player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.volume = 1.0
            player.play()
            print("IT WORKED?!?!?!?!?!")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //self.player = nil
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } catch {
            print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
        }
        
    }
```

I understand this is an error with my audio portion but I don't get what. I included most of my code because the request portion gets the file that I play from.

Any help would be appreciated.

*EDIT I think I might also need to mention that before the aforementioned error message I also get plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id*

Comment: What is the sense of loading data from the localhost (the current machine) asynchronously via HTTP?

Comment: @vadian I'm preparing to make this a web server. But in the hopes of testing I'm hosting it on my own machine.

Comment: If you are going to load the file from a server you cannot call `play(url: url)` right after resuming the task anyway,  because – as already mentioned – the data is loaded asynchronously. You have to call `play(url: savedURL)` inside the closure after saving the file locally.

Comment: how would I do that. Sorry if it's a bad question, I'm fairly new to swift and still getting the hand of thins.

Comment: Replace `play(url: url)` with `self.play(url: savedURL)` and move the line right after the `moveItem` line

Comment: Thanks. It seems now that the code print I'm WORKING but there is no audio. The plugin error ``` [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id ``` is also there. Would you happen to know how to solve that?

Comment: I've never seen that error message.

Comment: re: "AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id" are you trying to test on simulator? Try real device Also your `player` should be in class scope, not in function scope, otherwise it will be deallocated before player had a chance to play anything

Comment: Could you show an example where the Player should be? Sorry I'm new to swift.